# KVM Arch install - no network

Tags: virtualization, arch-linux, linux-kvm, qemu

I often use KVM to try out various Linux distros. All I have tried so far get an automatic network, Red Hat and Debian have all connected out of the box, no problem. Makes installations very easy.

But Arch does not, and it needs the network to install. No help from Google on this issue. I can't figure it out.

Do I need to do something more for the Arch VM to get a connection?

Comment: Have you read the [wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide#Installing_on_a_virtual_machine) about this? Also, what are you getting in Arch when you try to set up the network?